# Problem with first and last layers

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, creality-ender-5

I bought Ender-5 and if I print sample model in bundle SD, it’s just perfect.

[image: sample_cat]

But when I tested basic cube with raft, its base and top is just ugly. Even thought its 4 sides are perfect.

[image: raft]
[image: bottom]
[image: top]
[image: side]

- Ultimaker Cura 4.2.1
- Bed temperature 45 °C
- Extruder temperature 200 °C

Which setting(s) should I check futher?

Comment: What filament diameter have you set in the slicer? Note that Cura defaults to 2.85mm. This will cause severe under-extrusion with 1.75mm filament, although it won't affect the G-code files supplied with the printer.

Comment: The picture of the cube doesn't show signs of being printed with 2.85 mm (instead of 1.75 mm); see e.g. [*"Print came out like a wafer"*](/q/9821).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to ensure that your filament diameter is correctly set in your printer's CURA profile, and that your hot end is at the correct temperature for the material you are using. Additionally, you should not need a raft to print the cube, and should be able to do without a raft or brim.